# How can I start a process using activiti-restapi and soapui or restclient

Tags: process, soapui, restful-url, activiti, rest-client

I want to start a simple process that can be in activiti-explorer or I deployed,using activiti-rest api. I use SoapUI or RESTClient.Actually I wrote URL and I can see all of the process,after I start the process with rest-services, I can see the process started in SoapUI,becasuse the reponse is true,but in activiti-explorer,process isn t starting.What should I do? I m waiting your helps
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you deployed the activiti-webapp-explorer2 and activiti-webapp-rest as separate war files and each is using an in memory database.

This means, the applications are essentially seperate.

You have two choices.

1. Deploy as separate webapps but set them to use the same database instance/
2. Merge the rest API jar into the explorer webapp.

Both methods are acceptable.

Comment: Thank you for helping,but it solved,I added to media type {"processDefinitionKey":"Process's name"}